# how can i realize a video-wall on 3-9pc with vlc

Tags: video, multiple-monitors, streaming, media-player, vlc-media-player

i have to create a videowall, from 3 to 9 monitor.
every monitor as a pc.

actually, i stream from a server 9 movies with different istances of VLC, but i could also play on every machine the relative video with a single player.
there's no problem.

the real problem is that i really dont know how to sync the videos on a LAN...unfortunately there is a NETSYNC module inside VLC wich is NOT working.

---

here are some info about my setup:
videowall from 3 to 9 monitor  || 
from 3 to 9 pc, all with the same configuration ||
a gigabit router+switch for the "dedicated" LAN

---

im really stuck in this situation, if anyone has an idea or just a completely different solution, please, share it with me!

thanks a lot in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Try using the [latest RC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/releases/1.1.0-RC.html) (just use the zip version so you don't have to install it.)
2) If that is a no go, try the [latest nightly](http://nightlies.videolan.org/).
3) If that fails, report it as a bug. You'll get some help, feedback, or a fixed version there soon hopefully.

Comment: unfortunately the netsync module NEVER worked in vlc :(

Comment: Did you report it?